# Mostrar Resultado de um onResultScan em um RecycleView

Tags: java, android

Estou estou montando um *APP* para o curso, é sobre *Wi-Fi*, preciso lista a pesquisa de *Wi-Fi* disponível e colocar no *Recycleview*, no exemplo que vou mostrar ele esta listando em uma *ListView*, e no *Recycleview* não estou conseguindo fazer porque não consigo pegar o resultado do *onResultScan* e e jogar para o *recycle*(INICIANTE)

> Classe *MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Wifi.WiFiListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Wifi wiFi;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> itens;
    private List<ScanResult> scans;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.botao).setOnClickListener(this);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        itens = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, itens);
        // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itens);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Buscando....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        wiFi = Wifi.startScanWIFI(this, this);
    }

    public void onResultScan(Context arg0, Intent arg1, List<ScanResult> results) {
        scans = results;
        itens.clear();
        for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
            itens.add(scanResult.SSID /*+ " - " + scanResult.BSSID*/);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        //Configuro uma rede baseada nos dados encontrados.
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
       wifiConfiguration.BSSID = scans.get(arg2).BSSID;
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + scans.get(arg2).SSID + "\"";
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"mpt211992manaus\"";


        //Conecto na nova rede criada.

        WifiManager wifiManager = wiFi.getWifiManager(this);
        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
    }




}
```

> Class *Adapter_Wifi*

```
public class Adapter_Wifi extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você sabe implementar usando uma ListView mas não sabe implementar usando uma RecycleView, é isso?

Comment: isso, porque no recicle nao sei passar o resultado para o adapter, essa é a verdade.